# api calling of basecamp next steps

Tags: ios, objective-c, basecamp

I am getting the basecamp accounts in my app, now I want to call an api to get all the projects on basecamp with this account. I got error of about metadata etc.

Here is my API Call

```
    [NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                        onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://basecamp.com/XXXXXXX/api/v1/projects.json"]
                   usingParameters:nil
                       withAccount:currAccount
               sendProgressHandler:^(unsigned long long bytesSend, unsigned long long bytesTotal) { // e.g., update a progress indicator
               }
               responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
                   // Process the response
               }];
```

where currAccount is the object of NXOAuth2Account. Should i send something in parameter? If yes then how?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: actually it's too long to insert here , can you share you email id? Thanks

Comment: Just show me the first few lines. That should be good to get more details

Comment: Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0x7af46a40 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Are you sure about the project number "2497510" ? Because the error that you are getting is 404, which mean page not found. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i am sure and it is returning a list of project in browser but showing error in iOS , perhaps i miss the correct way of calling basecamp api.

Comment: somehow similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020328/how-to-update-a-plist-model-with-a-responsedata-from-oauth2-request?rq=1